# LC3 Address Book Error

Tags: lc3

Trying to get this code to run it's an address book for LC3 but I keep getting the following errors:

Line 21: Instruction references label 'BOOK' that cannot be represented in a 9-bit signed PC offset

Line 22: Instruction references label 'CURRENT' that cannot be represented in a 9-bit signed PC offset

Line 67: Instruction references label 'CURRENT' that cannot be represented in a 9-bit signed PC offset

Line 69: Instruction references label 'CURRENT' that cannot be represented in a 9-bit signed PC offset

Line 77: Instruction references label 'CURRENT' that cannot be represented in a 9-bit signed PC offset

Line 79: Instruction references label 'CURRENT' that cannot be represented in a 9-bit signed PC offset

Line 90: Instruction references label 'PROMPT5' that cannot be represented in a 9-bit signed PC offset

Code is here -> http://pastebin.com/8nZk3Dfd

Any help is appreciated, found this code online but want to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting these errors is because you have those variables after a larger number of strings. Keep in mind that each character in a `.STRINGZ` takes up a block of memory, and when your variables are too far from the code that wants to use them you get PC offset errors.

If you move your variables before your string prompts, those errors should go away.

Comment: I'm new to this LC3 and trying to understand assembly, I'm just trying to run this program and then inspect the code to see how the functions are being called, might be a long shot but would be awesome if you can help me to get this to run.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few errors fixed, your program will now assemble and at least print all of your strings, but I'll leave fixing the run-time errors to you.

.

```
.ORIG X3000 ;INITIALIZE PROGRAM

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;REGISTER DATA

;REGISTER 0 IS USED FOR INPUTTING INFORMATION BY THE USER
;REGISTER 1 IS USED AS THE MENU TESTER (CAN BE USED, ALWAYS INITIALIZED)
;REGISTER 2 IS COUNTER WITH R5 (CAN BE USED, ALWAYS REINITIALIZED)
;REGISTER 3 IS ASCII CONVERTER (CAN BE USED, ALWAYS REINITIALIZED)
;REGISTER 4 IS USED TO STORE MEMORY LOCATION OF BOOK (DO NOT USE)
;REGISTER 5 IS USED TO COUNT HOW MANY FILES HAVE BEEN STORED (DO NOT USE)
;REGISTER 6 IS USED AS A COUNTER IN STORING AND FINDING INFORMATION (DO NOT USE)
;REGISTER 7 IS UNUSED
;DO NOT USE R4, R5, R6, R7

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;START OF MAIN CODE
BRnzp MAIN
PROMPT  .STRINGZ "Enter 1 to add a new record and 2 to find a record and 0 to exit:" 
FULLBK  .STRINGZ "Address book is full. Would you like to find a record?"

MAIN
AND R5, R5, #0  ;INITIALIZES REGISTER
LD R0, BOOK
LDI R0, CURRENT
MENU            ;MENU FUNCTION
LEA R0, PROMPT  ;PROMPT THEM TO ADD OR FIND
PUTs
IN
LD R3, NTHIRTY  ;LOADS NEGATIVE THIRTY INTO R3
ADD R0,R0,R3    ;CONVERTS R0 INTO DECIMAL FROM ASCII 
BRnz SKIP   ;CONTINUE IF NOT A 0 OR NEGATIVE NUMBER

FNDLOOP LD R1, TWO  ;LOAD R2 WITH 2
ADD R1, R1, #-4 ;MAKES 2 INTO -2
ADD R1, R0, R1  ;TESTS TO SEE IF USER INPUT WAS A 1 TO FIND AN ADDRESS
BRn ADDLOOP ;LEAVE FIND LOOP
BRz FIND    ;CALLS THE FIND FUNCTION
BRp MENU    ;INVALID NUMBER, GOT BACK TO MENU

ADDLOOP LD R1, ONE  ;LOAD R1 WITH 1
ADD R1, R1, #-2 ;MAKES 1 INTO -1
ADD R1, R0, R1  ;TESTS TO SEE IF USER INPUT WAS A 1 TO ADD AN ADDRESS
BRnp SKIP   ;LEAVE ADD LOOP TO A HALT
BRz ADDRESS ;CALLS THE ADD FUNCTION

HOWFULL AND R2, R2, #0  ;INITIALIZES R2
ADD R2, R2, #-9 ;MAKES R2 -10
ADD R5, R5, #1  ;INCREMENTS R5 BY 1
ADD R2, R2, R5  ;ADDS R2 AND R5 TOGETHER, IF R5 BECOMES 10 IT WILL EQUAL 0
BRz BKFULL  ;IF R2 IS ZERO, ADDRESS BOOK IS FULL
BRnzp MENU  ;BACK TO THE BEGINNING

SKIP    
LEA R0, GBYE    ;PROMPTS A GOODBYE MESSAGE
PUTs
HALT        ;CALL PROGRAM TO A HALT

BKFULL
LEA R0, FULLBK  ;PROMPTS A FULL BOOK MESSAGE
PUTs
IN
LD R1, TWO  ;LOAD R2 WITH 2
ADD R1, R1, #-4 ;MAKES 2 INTO -2
ADD R1, R0, R1  ;TESTS TO SEE IF USER INPUT WAS A 1 TO FIND AN ADDRESS
BRz FIND    ;IF 0 CONTINUES TO FIND FUNCTION
HALT        ;CALL PROGRAM TO A HALT

ADDRESS
LD R6, EIGHT    ;INITIALIZES R6 TO BE 8 SO IT CAN LOOP 8 TIMES
LEA R0, PROMPT2 ;PROMPTS QUESTION TO ENTER A NAME
PUTs
LOOP1   IN      ;GET CHARACTER OF NAME
LD R4, CURRENT  ;LOAD ADDRESS OF NAME LOCATION
ADD R4, R4, #1  ;STORE RECORD INTO THE PLACE
ST R4, CURRENT
STR R0, R4, #0
ADD R6, R6, #-1 ;DECREASES COUNTER R6 BY 1
BRp LOOP1   ;IF IT IS STILL POSITIVE IT LOOPS TO COMPLETE THE NAME

LD R6, EIGHT    ;INITIALIZES R6 TO BE 8 SO IT CAN LOOP 8 TIMES
LEA R0, PROMPT3 ;PROMPTS QUESTION TO ENTER A PHONE NUMBER
PUTs
LOOP2   IN      ;GET CHARACTER OF RECORD
LD R4, CURRENT  ;LOAD ADDRESS OF NAME LOCATION
ADD R4, R4, #1  ;STORE RECORD INTO THE PLACE
ST R4, CURRENT
STR R0, R4, #0
ADD R6, R6, #-1 ;DECREASES COUNTER R6 BY 1
BRp LOOP2   ;IF IT IS STILL POSITIVE IT LOOPS TO COMPLETE THE PHONE NUMBER
LEA R0, THANKYOU
PUTs
BRNZP MENU  ;BACK TO MENU 

FIND
LEA R0, PROMPT2
IN

LEA R0, PROMPT3
IN

BRNZP MENU  ;BACK TO MENU

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;START OF .FILL DATA

NTHIRTY .FILL x-30
TEN .FILL #10
ONE .FILL #1
TWO .FILL #2
EIGHT   .FILL #8

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;START OF STRING PROMPTS

THANKYOU    .STRINGZ "Thank you!"
GBYE        .STRINGZ "Goodbye!"
PROMPT2     .STRINGZ "Enter in an 8 character or less name:"
PROMPT3     .STRINGZ "Enter in an 8 character or less number:"

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;START OF ADDRESS BOOK DATA

CURRENT .BLKW #1
BOOK    .BLKW #160

.END        ;END PROGRAM
```